# Creating a product attribute that goes into the catalog_product_entity_int table in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In Magento I am trying to create a product attribute that will go into the integer table for the Product EAV system. However, when I create the attribute it appears that the attribute is going varchar table.

Here is the code I am using for my modules setup script:

```
    <?php
$installer = $this;

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'review_index', array(

'type' => 'int',
'backend'=> '',
'visible' => 0,
'required' => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,

));

$installer->endSetup();
```

EDIT: As requested the contents for this row in the eav_attribute table:

```
entity_type_id: 4

attribute_code: review_index

attribute_model: NULL

backend_model: <blank>

backend_type: int

backend_table: <blank>

frontend_model: <blank>

frontend_input: text

frontend_label: <blank>

frontend_class: <blank>

source_model: <blank>

is_required: 0

is_user_defined: 1

default_value: <blank>

is_unique: 0

note: <blank>
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is are the settings stored in the database for this attribute? It will be in the eav_attribute table.

Comment: See changes to questions above.

Comment: That is strange. The database data looks correct for what you want.

I would try deleting from the database and then reinstall via script or maybe try using the attribute manager from the admin.

Comment: As it turns out, creating the attribute started out as an int, and then when I would update it in the admin panel, it would get changed to a varchar. For the sake of time I just put leading zeroes so that it would sort the way I wanted it to.